# Error building player for Android in Unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build

```
Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the Console for details.
C:\Users\4story\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\24.0.0-preview\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "C:/Users/4story/AppData/Local/Android/sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_

stderr[

]
stdout[

]
```

Please help me fix this. Why can't I build my project? I'm new to unity.

EDIT:
UNITY VERSION: 5.3.4f1 64 bit
Minimum api 10 aka 2.3.3 gingerbread (Note on sdk manager downloading sdk platform for gingerbread is not available for windows so I didnt download it... should I use higher api?)
android sdk tools 25.1.1

Can I build empty project for android? I mean ive been making games with android studio and everything was working like a charm but unity cant build.
Am I using a plugin? What's that?

There. Can you help me now?

**EDIT2**:
I wasnt expecting anything to change and it didn't
Empty project doesn't matter, repackaging resources still fails.
Does the minimum API matter? (on the blank project I tried 2.3.1 (which was in by itself) and 6.0 (because I have everything installed there with sdk manager))

Does SDK platforms installed matter?
Would It help to say that I get 2 Error messages, the above and one more which is exactly LIKE the above but below everything has this

```
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.Exec (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.String[] progress_strings, Single progress_value, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.CompileResources (System.String stagingArea, System.String packageName, UnityEditor.Android.AndroidLibraries androidLibraries)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcessInternal (System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

*Might aswell mention that I have to update bundle identifier every time I create a new project.*

Thanks for the help thus far however. Really appreciated.

***EDIT3***
Android sdk folder looked more like [...]/appdata/local/android/sdk and now it looks like C:\AndroidSDK\Android\sdk (not Android-sdk unless thats what you meant). So first part didn't do anything

However when I downloaded the sdk you provided me I could build the project just fine! Thanks for your help. Alot. I even tested it on a real device and everything was working. Didn't even have to download unity 5.4 beta I guess it was just a wrong sdk. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know what is causing this problem but do the following below. The problem will be fixed by the time you are done.

**1**. Make sure that there are **no** spaces in your SDKpath. So create a folder called `AndroidSDK` in the `C` directory.

**2**. Copy your `Android-sdk` folder to the `C:/AndroidSDK` directory.

Now, your SDK path should look like this:

```
C:/AndroidSDK/Android-sdk
```

**3**. Update your Android SDK path in the Unity Editor.

*Now, check if it works by trying to Build for Android again.*

If it fails, continue from below

**4**. Download [Unity 5.4 beta](http://unity3d.com/unity/beta).

**5**. Re-download [SDK](http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-windows.zip) then copy the file to `C:/AndroidSDK/Android-sdk`.

**6**. Go back to Unity and Update the path

[image]

**7**. Build the Project for Android again, it will show an **error** and ask you to update SDK.

[image]

Click on the "**Update Android SDK**" buttom. Unity will Automatically update your SDK. Your SDK should then look like something below. Your problem should be gone by now.

[image]