# Unable to list target platforms. Please make sure the android sdk path is correct

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

I am trying to build old unity version(v_4.6.3) project. but i have got a error. already i have got successful result, but current my sdk is updated with latest version.

http://screencast.com/t/u7lNiyoc

Here is my unity error log.

> ```
> Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to list target platforms. Please make sure the android sdk path is correct. See the Console for more details. 
> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="E:/Temp/sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:/Program Files (x86)/Unity/Editor/Data/BuildTargetTools/AndroidPlayer\sdktools.jar" -
>
> stderr[
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/utils/ILogger
> at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
> at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
> at SDKMain.main(SDKMain.java:128)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.utils.ILogger
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
> ... 3 more
> ]
>
> stdout[
>
> ]
> ```

How can i fix this issues. Thank you for advances. Kind Regards.

Answer (score 24):

The solution to this problem is constantly changing over time as Unity and the Android SDK change.

Note that his problem is presumably fixed in **Unity 2017.1**.

**LATEST SOLUTION**

1) For Windows, download ["tools_r25.2.3-windows.zip"](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-windows.zip?hl=id) and unzip it.

2) For MacOSX, download ["tools_r25.2.3-macosx.zip"](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-macosx.zip?hl=id) and unzip it.

3) Add the path of the unzipped SDK to the *Edit* -->*Preferences* ---> *External Tools* --->SDK  box.

**STILL NOT WORKING?**

Uninstall SDK Tools 25 and Android SDK Tools 26. Uninstall both SDK Platform-Tools and SDK Tools. Use version number below that.

**OLD SOLUTION**:

You did not setup your SDK [properly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36959457/3785314).

Follow the steps below to setup your Android SDK.

**1**. Make sure that there are **no** spaces in your SDKpath. So create a folder called `AndroidSDK` in the `C` directory.

**2**. Copy your `Android-sdk` folder to the `C:/AndroidSDK` directory.

Now, your SDK path should look like this:

```
C:/AndroidSDK/Android-sdk
```

**3**. Update your Android SDK path in the Unity Editor.

*Now, check if it works by trying to Build for Android again.*

If it fails, continue from below

**4**. Download the latest Unity version.

**5**. Re-download [SDK](http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-windows.zip) then copy the file to `C:/AndroidSDK/Android-sdk`.

**6**. Go back to Unity and Update the path

[image]

**7**. Build the Project for Android again, it will show an **error** and ask you to update SDK.

[image]

Click on the "**Update Android SDK**" buttom. Unity will Automatically update your SDK. Your SDK should then look like something below. Your problem should be gone by now.

[image]

Comment: This Helped me Unity 5.6.2 And i used  For MacOSX, download "tools_r25.2.3-macosx.zip" and unzip it. And Fallowed Old solution Mentioned. It just worked.

Comment: I can confirm Unity. 2017.1.2p1 still has this problem on a fresh installed Windows 10.

Comment: @GuneyOzsan It happens on most every new Unity update. I suggest you try the first solution in this answer. I expect it to still work fine

Comment: @Programmer Yes SDK tools 25.2.3 worked for me. Sad to see such key points are undocumented.

Comment: It's just that Android SDK keeps changing. You will see this problem more. Hopefully, one day, it will be gone

Comment: I had a similar problem but the solution for me was to set the environment variables: `JAVA_HOME`, `ANDROID_HOME`, `ANDROID_NDK_HOME` and update `PATH`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49764804/14934).

Comment: @MikeHenry Good to know. The installer is supposed to do that for you but failed for some reason. This problem seems to have different solutions depending on the circumstances. I will update this post to reflect that when I have time.

Comment: On Unity 2018.1 you'll probably need tools 25.2.5!!! But this answer led me to understand the issue, thanks.

Comment: @Luishg The answer keeps changing but it all boils down to the Unity and tool version mostly. Glad you find it helpful

Comment: I try this on Unity 2017.4.30f until "update button" but not working...

Comment: This solved my issue only by one step: rename my "tools" folder to other name and then copy "tools" of tools_r25.2.3-windows.zip into "Android-sdk". Rebuild your app. Injoy!