# (Unity android build error) Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to list target platforms issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, build-error

[Unable to list target platforms. Please make sure the android sdk path is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37313735/unable-to-list-target-platforms-please-make-sure-the-android-sdk-path-is-correc)

I have searched for this error. and many suggested me to downgrade the "tools" folder in the android sdk. So I did. But It didn't work...

So did anyone gone throgh with different solution????

thanks.

Below is my full error messages

---

Error:Invalid command android

UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

---

CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to list target platforms. Please make sure the android sdk path is correct. See the Console for more details. C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe -Xmx1024M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/AndroidSDK\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -

stderr[ Error:Invalid command android ] stdout[

] exit code: 64 UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandInternal (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandSafe (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

---

CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to update the SDK. Please run the SDK Manager manually to make sure you have the latest set of tools and the required platforms installed. See the Console for more details. C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe -Xmx1024M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/AndroidSDK\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" android update sdk -a -u -t tool,platform-tool,build-tools-23.0.2

stderr[ Error:Invalid command android ] stdout[

] exit code: 64 UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandInternal (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandSafe (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

---

Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to list target platforms. Please make sure the android sdk path is correct. See the Console for more details. C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe -Xmx1024M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/AndroidSDK\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -

stderr[ Error:Invalid command android ] stdout[

] exit code: 64

---

[image: External Tool Settings]

Comment: Are you using 5.6?

Comment: yes My unity is 5.6.0f.

Comment: Is this the first time you are building for Android? Can you post screenshot of your Unity Preference settings where you put the SDK url?

Comment: yes it is my first time building for Android.and I just uninstalled my unity to install  again. But my SDK URL was <C:\AndroidSDK>like shown in the errors..<C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131> was my JDK url

Comment: I just want to see the screenshot of how you set it up in Unity Editor.  There is a SDK, JDK and NDK(Optional). Can you post that? Edit-->Preferences...-->External Tools then scroll to where it says Android and take a screenshot of it.

Comment: yeap reinstalling doesn't work either.

Comment: I uploaded the screenshot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143846/discussion-between-user2257636-and-programmer).

Comment: I am gonna write here the solution cause I know that someone will definitely search for this. I am sure. I had to check SDK manager and tools to uninstall SDK Tools 25 and Android SDK Tools 26.Install something below. Unity does not simply support.  Download Unity 20017 beta for a possible fix. Again thx to @Programmer

Comment: Modified that into the other answer to put the answer into one place instead of fragmented answers. This will make it easier for other people to find a solution since there are different solutions for this issue.