# Unity Android not building, official fix not working

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, sdk

After changing SDK tools for Android, I can no longer build. I Have had this issue before, and managed to solve it with this fix:

[This old fix](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/is...-android-sdk-tools-25-dot-3-1-version-is-used)

BUT, the link for the older SDK tools does not exist on the Android website anymore. I cannot find it anywhere.

I know that I just need to find the Windows "tools_r25.2.3-windows.zip" , but it doesn't exist in the Android archive anywhere that I can find.

Does anyone have an alternative place that this will work?

Here is my error:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to list target platforms. Please make sure 
the android sdk path is correct. See the Console for more details. 
C:/Java/jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -
Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/AndroidSDK/sdk\tools" -
 Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:\Program 

Files\Unity_5.6\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -

stderr[
Error:Invalid command android
]
stdout[

]
exit code: 64
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, 
UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandInternal (System.String javaExe, 
System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, 
System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit                 
waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandSafe (System.String javaExe, 
System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, 
System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit 
waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the links changed.
If *tools_r25.2.3-windows.zip*  is missing from the Google url, you can find it [here](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-windows.zip?hl=id).

For MacOSX, you can find *tools_r25.2.3-macosx.zip* [here](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-macosx.zip?hl=id).

Remember that if that solution does not work for you, you can check for other things to try [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37314122/3785314).

Comment: Don't forget to accept answers if your problem is solved.