# Where is adb located when installing Unity and Android SDK for Mac?

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine, adb

I'm getting Android Build Failures and would like to locate `adb` to do some queries like `adb devices` but where is `adb` installed? I've already installed the Android SDK for Unity.

Answer (score -8, accepted):

> Where is adb installed when it comes with unity?

adb is **never** installed when you install Unity. You are responsible for downloading, installing and setting up *Android SDK* and then manually setting the paths in Unity.

You download Android SDK, then JDK and setup the paths in Unity. 
That's it. If you want to build for Android with *IL2CPP* then you must also download the Android NDK and also set the link up in the Editor.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37314122/3785314) post if you have problems setting it up.

If you want to see the SDK path go here:

**EDIT**:

Go to *Edit* ---> *Preferences* --->*External Tools* then scroll down to *SDK* under *Android*, you will see the SDK path there.

Once you find the SDK path, *"adb.exe"* will be located at `<SDK_PATH>/platform-tools`.

Comment: I've installed Unity and when I wanted to deploy for Android it asked me to install another package `Android SDK` after that i was able to deploy apps, i didn't have to add any path in any configuration. So i am guessing, that this package was responsible of taking care of installing ADB

Comment: When Unity installs, the Android SDK is **not** installed automatically. It may ask you if it should be installed when you want to build for Android but that's not installed automatically. Even [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/540/Documentation/Manual/android-sdksetup.html) Unity doc explains how to set it up.  Maybe this has changed. *See my edit for how to find the path.*

Comment: Ok, I am not saying it is shipped with Unity, but there is an executable for it, that is being suggested by Unity to be downloaded.

Comment: Hi, you just changed the most important part of your question rendering my answer useless. It will be better to add **EDIT** in  your question then add those new details to it then I will modify my answer to update it. That's the proper way to do that.

Comment: Now, if I modify my answer to say that the path is at `/Users/chavez/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools`, that would be wrong because that is different on every machine. If it is setup by another person, that used a different path it would be wrong. Like I mentioned in my answer, the path can be found at *Edit* ---> *Preferences* ---> *External Tools* then scroll down to *SDK* under *Android*. This is the proper way to find the path and will work on all supported platforms.

Comment: We install ours to the ~/Documents directory along with other various tools since it's easy to duplicate on all of our build machines. Where you install it is a personal preference.

Comment: That's what I am trying to tell OP. Putting `/Users/chavez/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools` as answer is wrong since people use different paths. Checking the Editor settings will be appropriate.

Comment: Sorry, I've answered to quick and exposed as well my username...darn, Can you at least Just keep your Edit part and point out that the `adb` is located in `platform-tools`

Comment: @Programmer I believe this is no longer true.  Please see my answer.

Comment: -1 -- Dude.  There's a checkbox when you install Unity that says "Install Android SDK".  And in that dialog box, those paths are grayed out and there's a checkbox for using the "Android SDK Tools Installed with Unity (recommended)"; it definitely comes with Unity.  So where did it get installed to?  I don't care where it is on Joe Blow's machine, I just want to know where Unity puts those files by default.

Answer (score 21):

From @Programmer's answer, this line is no longer true:

> You are responsible for downloading, installing and setting up Android SDK and then manually setting the paths in Unity.

Unity now allows and [encourages you to install the Android SDK via their Unity Hub](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-sdksetup.html):

> Use the Unity Hub to install Android Build Support and the required Android SDK & NDK tools:
>   [image]

From the same page, I found `adb.exe` is located at: `/c/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.2.1f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/SDK/platform-tools/adb.exe`

Comment: Please leave a comment if you're going to down vote.  We can't improve it if you don't say why it's wrong and also it's correct so why are you down voting?

Comment: Does this SDK belong to Unity, or Unity just uses an external SDK. I am asking because I wonder is it possible to use this SDK for my own purpose?

Comment: I'm not a lawyer @unlut but I would guess it belongs to Unity.  However if you fall with in their free category, i.e. you're not making "enough" money then you might be able to use this anyway for free if it is allowed in their terms and conditions.

Answer (score 4):

Updated answer for 2023:

`C:\Program Files\Unity Editors\YOURVERSION\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools`

Answer (score 2):

For OSX users:

/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2022.1.0b16/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/SDK/platform-tools/adb