# Android SDK tools installation for Unity

Tags: android, sdk, unity-game-engine

After I installed an older Unity version (5.6.0f3) I can't build a simple android app:

> Unable to list target platforms. Please make sure the android sdk path
>   is correct. See the Console for more details.  See the Console for
>   details.

As I understand I need Android tools 25.2.5 or earlier in order to build android apps in Unity 5.6.0f3.

According to  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37313735/unable-to-list-target-platforms-please-make-sure-the-android-sdk-path-is-correc) instruction I need just to add the path of the unzipped SDK to the Edit -->Preferences ---> External Tools --->SDK box. The problem is that after that Unity is not accepting this path and asks me to choose a different one.

While following [this](https://androidsdkoffline.blogspot.com/p/android-sdk-tools.html) instruction, since I have a mac, I downloaded and unzipped the file and double-clicked android.bat and installed the recommended packages. But the problem remains, I still see the error message.

What might be the problem and how it can it be fixed?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you have tried the other answer and it didn't work, you should show us what you did. Post a screenshot of where you put the SDK path in the EDitor. Post a screenshot of the folder you put/unzipped the SDK. Without doing this it would be hard to tell what you did wrong/

Answer (score 0):

The reason Unity does not accept the path is because you are not linking the right folder for the sdk path. You may have to play around with the inner/outer folders of the sdk path in order to get it right.

On my mac the file path after installing the sdk is Library/Android/sdk (this is installed from Android Studio so that path may be a bit different).

And on my windows the correct folder is just the unzipped outer folder e.g tools_r25.2.3-windows

Answer (score 0):

SDK / ADK: is the path to the folder that contains "platform-tools" folder (which contain ADB binary)

[image]

JDK: is the folder that contains the bin folder that contains java / javac (comipler) binary

[image]

NDK: download and unpack this massive ugly zip with 56k files in it. It should be version r13b - untiy doesn't like newer versions. No need to install anything

[image]

Thankfully for new versions of Unity assist you in managing those dependencies via the hub, but I am posting the screenshots for future reference as I often find myself looking for the very same answer