# Unity Facebook SDK Error "Win32Exception: ApplicationName=" Unity after implementing facebook SDK

Tags: c#, android, facebook, unity-game-engine, building

I have just finished implementing facebook into my android app, and have compiled it many times with no issues before the implementation - any ideas on what this error means? It was compiling fine before the facebook sdk was installed, so it can't be the version of the android sdk. I think it may be to do with the hashes, but I'm unsure.

https://pastebin.com/ySti997g

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources.
C:\Users\Will\AppData\Local\Android\sdk2\build-tools\25.0.3\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J "gen" -M "AndroidManifest.xml" -S "res" -I "C:\Users\Will\AppData\Local\Android\sdk2\platforms\android-25\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages
```

.......etc (on pastebin)

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37313735/unable-to-list-target-platforms-please-make-sure-the-android-sdk-path-is-correc)

Comment: Didn't work - I'm sure it has something to do with the Facebook SDK but I don't know what exactly.