# Unable to list target platforms. ArCore with Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

I'm trying to use Unity 2017.2.0b10 to check Google ArCore, but when I try  to Build the project I'm getting this Error:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to list target platforms. Please make sure the android sdk path is correct. See the Console for more details. 
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_144\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="E:/AndroidSDK/sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:\Program Files\Unity 2017.2.0b10\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -

stderr[
Error:Invalid command android
]
stdout[

]
exit code: 64
```

If anyone has any idea please let me know.

Comment: See [Unable to list target platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37313735/unable-to-list-target-platforms-please-make-sure-the-android-sdk-path-is-correc)

Answer (score 2):

download and extract below link into Android_SDK_root/tools -> tools

```
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.5-windows.zip
```