# Unity unable to list target platforms

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm a little bit new working on Unity and I've developed a VR game, everything goes well until I try to create the apk in the Build Settings. I got this error:

[image: Error Log1]

The console Log in unity is this:

[image: Console Log]

I've searched the same topic and tried replacing the "Tools" folder of my sdk root but still got the problem. If anyone can help me I would appreciate it.

Comment: The issue  seems to arise even when fixed. Can you try the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37314122/3785314) answer?

Comment: if you have jdk9, downgrade to jdk1.8.x https://forum.unity.com/threads/java-9-jdk-9-support-by-unity-android.499354/

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error. I had to set some environment variables and restart Unity in order to get it to work:

- Set the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` to the JDK location.
- Set the environment variable `ANDROID_HOME` to the Android SDK location.
- Set the environment variable `ANDROID_NDK_HOME` to the Android NDK location.
- Add the JDK tools directory to your `PATH`, ie C:\Program Files\Android Studio\jre\bin.

Source: [Oculus Android Development Software Setup](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/mobilesdk/latest/concepts/mobile-studio-setup-android/)

It looks like you're on a Mac, so to set environment variables, see [How do I set environment variables on OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106778/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-on-os-x)

To edit environment variables in Windows 10: Windows Settings > Find a setting > Edit environment variables for your account (or Edit the system environment variables).

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a fix that worked for me!

https://answers.unity.com/questions/1320150/unable-to-list-target-platform.html

- Rename android sdk tool folder : [Your Android SDK root]/tools ->
  toolsXXXX
- Download SDK Tools:
  http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.5-windows.zip
- Extract that to Android SDK root
- Build your project