# Unable to list target platforms Unity 2018.1.0f2

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a problem when i build / export my game into android's APK.
i've already replace latest tools folder to my SDK path but the problem still don't fixed.
So i tried to upgrade my Unity from 2017.2.0f3 into Unity 2018.1.0f2 and reconfigure my SDK path but still not working.

[There's the error notice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hm4i4.png)

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to list target platforms. Please make sure the android sdk path is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37313735/unable-to-list-target-platforms-please-make-sure-the-android-sdk-path-is-correc)

Answer (score 0):

Go through Unitys preferences and make sure android SDK Java SDK paths are configured. I had this error recently on a fresh install, the solution was to install https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools ( also setting paths to platform tools in your system path can be useful while at it)