# AdMob: CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the Console for details

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, admob, tango

I have been trying to solve this issue for about a week now. Even when removing admob the problem persists. This leads me to believe something has changed in the way Unity does android. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Since I am developing for Google's project tango, for whatever reason the package I import contains 7 mainfests. I think this is part of the problem, but deleting any of them causes errors.

```
C:\Users\Brandon\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\24.0.0-preview\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "C:/Users/Brandon/AppData/Local/Android/sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages android.support.v7.appcompat:com.google.firebase:com.google.unity:com.google.unity:com.google.android.gms.ads.impl:com.google.android.gms.ads:com.google.android.gms.base:com.google.android.gms:com.google.android.gms.tasks:android.support.v4:com.google.atap.tangocloudlib:com.projecttango.unity:com.google.atap.tango.uxsupportlibrary:com.google.atap.tangohelperlib:com.projecttango.unityuxhelper -S "E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.1.1\res" -S "E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\firebase-common-9.0.1\res" -S "E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-unity-wrapper\res" -S "E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-ads-9.0.1\res" -S "E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-ads-lite-9.0.1\res" -S "E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-9.0.1\res" -S "E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-basement-9.0.1\res" -S "E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-tasks-9.0.1\res" -S "E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-v4-23.1.1\res" -S "E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\tango-ux-support-library\res" -S "E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\UnityUxHelper\res"

stderr[

]
stdout[
Configurations:
 (default)
 v11
 v14
 mdpi-v4
 hdpi-v4
 xhdpi-v4

Files:
  drawable\ic_launcher.png
    Src: (mdpi-v4) E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\UnityUxHelper\res\drawable-mdpi\ic_launcher.png
    Src: (hdpi-v4) E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\UnityUxHelper\res\drawable-hdpi\ic_launcher.png
    Src: (xhdpi-v4) E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\UnityUxHelper\res\drawable-xhdpi\ic_launcher.png
  layout\tango_ux_layout.xml
    Src: () E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\UnityUxHelper\res\layout\tango_ux_layout.xml
  values\strings.xml
    Src: () E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\UnityUxHelper\res\values\strings.xml
  values\styles.xml
    Src: () E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\UnityUxHelper\res\values\styles.xml
    Src: (v11) E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\UnityUxHelper\res\values-v11\styles.xml
    Src: (v14) E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\UnityUxHelper\res\values-v14\styles.xml
  AndroidManifest.xml
    Src: () AndroidManifest.xml

Resource Dirs:
  Type drawable
    drawable\ic_launcher.png
      Src: (mdpi-v4) E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\UnityUxHelper\res\drawable-mdpi\ic_launcher.png
      Src: (hdpi-v4) E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\UnityUxHelper\res\drawable-hdpi\ic_launcher.png
      Src: (xhdpi-v4) E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\UnityUxHelper\res\drawable-xhdpi\ic_launcher.png
  Type layout
    layout\tango_ux_layout.xml
      Src: () E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\UnityUxHelper\res\layout\tango_ux_layout.xml
  Type values
    values\strings.xml
      Src: () E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\UnityUxHelper\res\values\strings.xml
    values\styles.xml
      Src: () E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\UnityUxHelper\res\values\styles.xml
      Src: (v11) E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\UnityUxHelper\res\values-v11\styles.xml
      Src: (v14) E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\UnityUxHelper\res\values-v14\styles.xml
Including resources from package: C:\Users\Brandon\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar
applyFileOverlay for drawable
trying overlaySet Key=exception_container_shadow.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=hold_steady_bubble_level_err.png
trying overlaySet Key=hold_steady_bubble_level_ok.png
trying overlaySet Key=ic_exception_i_am_dizzy.png
trying overlaySet Key=ic_exception_i_am_lost.png
trying overlaySet Key=ic_exception_i_cant_see.png
trying overlaySet Key=ic_exception_system.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_full_open_on_phone.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_disabled.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_focused.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_pressed.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_disabled.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_focused.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_pressed.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_disabled.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_focused.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_pressed.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light_disabled.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light_focused.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light_pressed.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_ic_googleplayservices.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_icon_dark.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_icon_dark_disabled.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_icon_dark_focused.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_icon_dark_pressed.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_icon_light.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_icon_light_disabled.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_icon_light_focused.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_icon_light_normal.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_icon_light_pressed.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_text_dark.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_text_dark_disabled.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_text_dark_focused.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_text_dark_normal.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_text_dark_pressed.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_text_light.xml
```

Some problems have been fixed based on the below suggestions. Here is my new error:

```
Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the Console for details.
C:\AndroidSdk\android-sdk-windows\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "C:/AndroidSdk/android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-23\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages android.support.v7.appcompat:com.google.firebase:com.google.unity:com.google.unity:com.google.android.gms.ads.impl:com.google.android.gms.ads:com.google.android.gms.base:com.google.android.gms:com.google.android.gms.tasks:android.support.v4:com.google.atap.tangocloudlib:com.projecttango.unity:com.google.atap.tango.uxsupportlibrary:com.google.atap.tangohelperlib:com.projecttango.unityuxhelper -S "E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.1.1\res" -S "E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\firebase-common-9.0.1\res" -S "E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-unity-wrapper\res" -S "E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-ads-9.0.1\res" -S "E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-ads-lite-9.0.1\res" -S "E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-9.0.1\res" -S "E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-basement-9.0.1\res" -S "E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-tasks-9.0.1\res" -S "E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-v4-23.1.1\res" -S "E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\tango-ux-support-library\res" -S "E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\UnityUxHelper\res"

stderr[
E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.1.1\res\layout\abc_screen_toolbar.xml:27: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:touchscreenBlocksFocus from <android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer>
E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.1.1\res\layout\abc_screen_toolbar.xml: note: using v21 attributes; synthesizing resource com.OwlArrowGames.TangoSportsVR:layout/abc_screen_toolbar for configuration v21.
AndroidManifest.xml:23: Tag <provider> attribute authorities has invalid character '$'.
]
stdout[
Configurations:
 (default)
 v11
 v14
 mdpi-v4
 hdpi-v4
 xhdpi-v4

Files:
  drawable\ic_launcher.png
    Src: (mdpi-v4) E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\UnityUxHelper\res\drawable-mdpi\ic_launcher.png
    Src: (hdpi-v4) E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\UnityUxHelper\res\drawable-hdpi\ic_launcher.png
    Src: (xhdpi-v4) E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\UnityUxHelper\res\drawable-xhdpi\ic_launcher.png
  layout\tango_ux_layout.xml
    Src: () E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\UnityUxHelper\res\layout\tango_ux_layout.xml
  values\strings.xml
    Src: () E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\UnityUxHelper\res\values\strings.xml
  values\styles.xml
    Src: () E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\UnityUxHelper\res\values\styles.xml
    Src: (v11) E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\UnityUxHelper\res\values-v11\styles.xml
    Src: (v14) E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\UnityUxHelper\res\values-v14\styles.xml
  AndroidManifest.xml
    Src: () AndroidManifest.xml

Resource Dirs:
  Type drawable
    drawable\ic_launcher.png
      Src: (mdpi-v4) E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\UnityUxHelper\res\drawable-mdpi\ic_launcher.png
      Src: (hdpi-v4) E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\UnityUxHelper\res\drawable-hdpi\ic_launcher.png
      Src: (xhdpi-v4) E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\UnityUxHelper\res\drawable-xhdpi\ic_launcher.png
  Type layout
    layout\tango_ux_layout.xml
      Src: () E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\UnityUxHelper\res\layout\tango_ux_layout.xml
  Type values
    values\strings.xml
      Src: () E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\UnityUxHelper\res\values\strings.xml
    values\styles.xml
      Src: () E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\UnityUxHelper\res\values\styles.xml
      Src: (v11) E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\UnityUxHelper\res\values-v11\styles.xml
      Src: (v14) E:\Repos\TangoSportsVR_2.0MIRA\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\UnityUxHelper\res\values-v14\styles.xml
Including resources from package: C:\AndroidSdk\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-23\android.jar
applyFileOverlay for drawable
trying overlaySet Key=exception_container_shadow.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=hold_steady_bubble_level_err.png
trying overlaySet Key=hold_steady_bubble_level_ok.png
trying overlaySet Key=ic_exception_i_am_dizzy.png
trying overlaySet Key=ic_exception_i_am_lost.png
trying overlaySet Key=ic_exception_i_cant_see.png
trying overlaySet Key=ic_exception_system.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_full_open_on_phone.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_disabled.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_focused.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_pressed.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_disabled.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_focused.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_pressed.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_disabled.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_focused.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_pressed.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light_disabled.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light_focused.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light_pressed.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_ic_googleplayservices.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_icon_dark.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_icon_dark_disabled.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_icon_dark_focused.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_icon_dark_pressed.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_icon_light.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_icon_light_disabled.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_icon_light_focused.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_icon_light_normal.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_icon_light_pressed.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_text_dark.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_text_dark_disabled.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_text_dark_focused.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_text_dark_normal.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_text_dark_pressed.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_text_light.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_text_light_disabled.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_text_light_focused.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_text_light_normal.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_text_light_pressed.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_action_bar_item_background_material.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_btn_borderless_material.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_btn_check_material.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_000.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_015.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_btn_colored_material.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_btn_default_mtrl_shape.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_btn_radio_material.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_btn_radio_to_on_mtrl_000.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_btn_radio_to_on_mtrl_015.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_btn_rating_star_off_mtrl_alpha.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_btn_rating_star_on_mtrl_alpha.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00001.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_cab_background_internal_bg.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_cab_background_top_material.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_cab_background_top_mtrl_alpha.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_control_background_material.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_dialog_material_background_dark.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_dialog_material_background_light.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_edit_text_material.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_ic_clear_mtrl_alpha.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_ic_commit_search_api_mtrl_alpha.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_ic_go_search_api_mtrl_alpha.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_ic_menu_copy_mtrl_am_alpha.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_ic_menu_cut_mtrl_alpha.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_ic_menu_moreoverflow_mtrl_alpha.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_ic_menu_paste_mtrl_am_alpha.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_ic_menu_selectall_mtrl_alpha.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_ic_voice_search_api_mtrl_alpha.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_item_background_holo_dark.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_item_background_holo_light.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_list_divider_mtrl_alpha.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_list_focused_holo.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_list_longpressed_holo.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_list_pressed_holo_dark.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_list_pressed_holo_light.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_list_selector_background_transition_holo_dark.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_list_selector_background_transition_holo_light.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_list_selector_holo_dark.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_list_selector_holo_light.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_popup_background_mtrl_mult.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_ratingbar_full_material.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_scrubber_control_off_mtrl_alpha.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_scrubber_control_to_pressed_mtrl_000.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_scrubber_control_to_pressed_mtrl_005.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_scrubber_primary_mtrl_alpha.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_scrubber_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_seekbar_thumb_material.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_seekbar_track_material.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_spinner_textfield_background_material.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_switch_thumb_material.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_switch_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_tab_indicator_material.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_tab_indicator_mtrl_alpha.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_text_cursor_material.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_textfield_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_textfield_search_material.xml
trying overlaySet Key=app_banner.png
trying overlaySet Key=app_icon.png
applyFileOverlay for layout
trying overlaySet Key=component_hold_steady.xml
trying overlaySet Key=exception_component.xml
trying overlaySet Key=layout_connection.xml
trying overlaySet Key=layout_tango_ux.xml
trying overlaySet Key=activity_main.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_action_bar_title_item.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_action_bar_up_container.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_action_bar_view_list_nav_layout.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_action_menu_item_layout.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_action_menu_layout.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_action_mode_bar.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_action_mode_close_item_material.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_activity_chooser_view.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_activity_chooser_view_list_item.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_alert_dialog_button_bar_material.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_alert_dialog_material.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_dialog_title_material.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_expanded_menu_layout.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_list_menu_item_checkbox.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_list_menu_item_icon.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_list_menu_item_layout.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_list_menu_item_radio.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_popup_menu_item_layout.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_screen_content_include.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_screen_simple.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_screen_simple_overlay_action_mode.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_screen_toolbar.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_search_dropdown_item_icons_2line.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_search_view.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_select_dialog_material.xml
trying overlaySet Key=notification_media_action.xml
trying overlaySet Key=notification_media_cancel_action.xml
trying overlaySet Key=notification_template_big_media.xml
trying overlaySet Key=notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml
trying overlaySet Key=notification_template_lines.xml
trying overlaySet Key=notification_template_media.xml
trying overlaySet Key=notification_template_part_chronometer.xml
trying overlaySet Key=notification_template_part_time.xml
trying overlaySet Key=select_dialog_item_material.xml
trying overlaySet Key=select_dialog_multichoice_material.xml
trying overlaySet Key=select_dialog_singlechoice_material.xml
trying overlaySet Key=support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item.xml
applyFileOverlay for anim
trying overlaySet Key=abc_fade_in.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_fade_out.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_grow_fade_in_from_bottom.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_popup_enter.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_popup_exit.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_shrink_fade_out_from_bottom.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_slide_in_bottom.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_slide_in_top.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_slide_out_bottom.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_slide_out_top.xml
applyFileOverlay for animator
applyFileOverlay for interpolator
applyFileOverlay for transition
applyFileOverlay for xml
applyFileOverlay for raw
applyFileOverlay for color
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_text_dark.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_text_light.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_background_cache_hint_selector_material_dark.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_background_cache_hint_selector_material_light.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_color_highlight_material.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_primary_text_disable_only_material_dark.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_primary_text_disable_only_material_light.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_primary_text_material_dark.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_primary_text_material_light.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_search_url_text.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_secondary_text_material_dark.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_secondary_text_material_light.xml
trying overlaySet Key=switch_thumb_material_dark.xml
trying overlaySet Key=switch_thumb_material_light.xml
applyFileOverlay for menu
```

Comment: Create a new empty project and see if it runs. This will tell you if the proble is from your project or unity

Comment: An empty project also does not work. I just updated to Unity 5.3.5 if that helps at all.

Comment: Wanted to verify that this is a unity problem. take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow direction from this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36959457/3785314). It's a long process and I see no need to re-post that. That should solve  your problem. When you are done, first test it with an empty project before testing it with your current project.Don't skip any step. Comment if there is any problem.

Comment: This worked to fix the problems I was having with a blank project. I now have an entirely new error that I will detail in the original message. I think this is now entirely related to admob.

Comment: @BMARX123 At least you can build blank projects. Now the problem is plugin. The more plugins you use, the more likely there will be plugin error for android. I suggest you start a new project. Add the first plugin then test. Add if works, add the second plugin then test. Let me know which one failed.

Comment: It looks like google admob itself causes unity to error out.