# Can't see my UI text after press play in Unity Cardboard project (Unity 5.4.0b21)

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

Problem： I can't see my UI text anywhere even​ it's in the Cardboard camera range.

screenshot:

[image]

I am using Unity version 5.4.0b21 and some people said it can be fixed by downgrading to Unity version 5.3.

However, I can't downgrade my Unity since I faced "Failed to build" problem before and I sloved this by using beta version Unity.
I follow the answer in this post : [Error building player for Android in Unity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36957963/error-building-player-for-android-in-unity?rq=1)

So I need a way to fix this without downgrading my Unity, thanks!!!

Comment: yup, looks like its the UI rendertexture bug, also mentioned in cardboard known issues. Have to wait for the fix (which might be still few weeks away), or downgrade to 5.3.4f1: https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/ui-elements-arent-rendered-to-rendertexture

Comment: I fixed this problem by upgrading my Unity to 5.4.0b22 and it can show UI text normally.
Thanks bro!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem by upgrading my Unity to 5.4.0b22 and it can show UI text normally. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2Yfy.png

So if you are facing this issue, try upgrading your Unity to 5.4.0b22!

Comment: and take backup..that is still in beta and could have other issues